# "ListenerOffset" property was already registered by "UserControl"

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to implement the "Scroll to load more" function. A custom binding is attached to check if ScrollViewer verticalOffset property has changed. The following code is used to register the binding on the ListBox load.

```
public static ScrollViewer scrollViewer;
public static DependencyProperty offsetChangeListener;
public static Binding binding;

private void initScrollViewerMonitor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //get the ScrollViewer from the ListBox
    scrollViewer = GetDescendantByType(accountHistoryList, typeof(ScrollViewer)) as ScrollViewer;


    //attach to custom binding to check if ScrollViewer verticalOffset property has changed
    if (binding == null || offsetChangeListener == null)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("VerticalOffset") { Source = scrollViewer };
        offsetChangeListener = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                "ListenerOffset",
                                typeof(object),
                                typeof(UserControl),
                                new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollChanged));
        scrollViewer.SetBinding(offsetChangeListener, binding);
    }
}
```

But when ListBox is reloaded in second time, the following error appear.

> **System.ArgumentException:** ''ListenerOffset' property was already
>   registered by "UserControl".'

Can I unregister it on unloaded?

Comment: Besides that a DependencyProperty field should be static, there are also mandatory naming conventions The backing field of a ListenerOffset dependency property should be named ListenerOffsetProperty. Thoroughly read [Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties) and [Attached Properties Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview).

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is the Dependency Property is getting Registered multiple times under the same name and owner. Dependency Properties are intended to have a single owner, and should be statically instanced. If you don't statically instance them, an attempt will be made to register them for each instance of the control.

Make your DependencyProperty declaration static on top (not inside function)

```
public static DependencyProperty offsetChangeListener = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                "ListenerOffset",
                                typeof(object),
                                typeof(UserControl),
                                new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollChanged));
```

Also check "typeof(UserControl)" should be the actual control not its base class.The third parameter to RegisterAttached (ownerType) must always be the class that declares the property.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Properties should be assigned statically and should not be instance based. The exception is telling you that the property has already been registered by the type `UserControl`.

> A dependency property identifier that should be used to set the value
>   of a **public static readonly** field in your class. That identifier is
>   then used to reference the dependency property later, for operations
>   such as setting its value programmatically or obtaining metadata.
>   [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597495(v=vs.110).aspx)

Now I can see you are checking for an attached property, however your are checking `if(binding == null) { ... }` but you are defining `var binding` lower down. The `var ..` is creating a new variable `binding` not using your class variable `binding`.  Therefore `var binding is not equal to binding`... This may be irrelevant in your instance.

Now basically what you want to do is create your `offsetChangeListener` a **`static readonly`** property such as.

```
static readonly DependencyProperty offsetChangeListener = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ListenerOffset",
                                                                                                typeof(object),
                                                                                                typeof(UserControl),
                                                                                                new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollChanged));
```

Now you need to track wether you have registered the binding however if you only register in the init stages (ie constructor etc) you can be sure you have only registered it once.

```
private void initScrollViewerMonitor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var binding = new Binding("VerticalOffset") { Source = scrollViewer };
    scrollViewer.SetBinding(offsetChangeListener, binding);
}
```